# Issue with jScrollPane and display

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

So having some issues with jScrollPane.

Here is my html:

```
<div id=wrapper">
    <div id="external">
    </div>
</div>
```

And then my js, which is done in classes etc, thus the no `$()`. Earlier the `_parentDiv` is set to `$("#external")`

```
this._internal = $('<div id="internal"></div');
this._parentDiv.html(this._internal);
Next I add some content to this._internal
this._internal.jScrollPane({autoReinitialise: true});
```

Any ideas? It looks like it loads, but I never get the scrollbar.  The jspContainer and jspPane are there, but